# Visualisation color palette query javascript circosjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using a javascript library for some visualisation (circosjs).

In the CSS file, I see this.
https://cdn.rawgit.com/nicgirault/circosJS/master/dist/colorBrewer.css

May I know what this representation actually means?

```
.YlOrBr .q0-3{fill:rgb(255,247,188)}
.YlOrBr .q1-3{fill:rgb(254,196,79)}
.YlOrBr .q2-3{fill:rgb(217,95,14)}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **The fill property can accept any CSS color value.**
>
> - Named colors — orange
> - Hex colors — #FF9E2C
> - RGB and RGBa colors — rgb(255, 158, 44) and rgba(255, 158, 44, .5)
> - HSL and HSLa colors — hsl(32, 100%, 59%) and hsla(32, 100%, 59%, .5)
>
> As a bonus, fill also accepts the patterns of SVG shapes that are
>   defined inside of a defs element:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/fill/

As they say *The fill property in CSS is for filling in the color of a SVG shape.*